# Select certain elements between two elements [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know if it's possible to select certain elements, crawling up the DOM, between two points.

Below is an example of the tree. My desire is to select all of the `labels` with a `data-tagname` attribute, starting from the `input` and ending at the `.parent`. The idea then is to set it as the input's name i.e name="one_two_three_four".

I can do this for a specific DOM tree by explicitly traversing upwards to the relevant elements. For example:

```js
$('input').each(function(){
    let label = 
        $(this).parent().parent()
               .parent().parent()
               .parent().parent()
               .prev('[data-tagname]')
               .attr('data-tagname')
          + '_' 
          + $(this).parent().parent()
               .parent().parent()
               .prev('[data-tagname]')
               .attr('data-tagname')
          + '_' 
          + $(this).parent().parent()
               .prev('[data-tagname]')
               .attr('data-tagname')
          + '_' 
          + $(this).prev('[data-tagname]')
                   .attr('data-tagname');
    $(this).attr('name', label);
    // 
    $(this).attr('placeholder', label);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="stop-here">
    <label data-tagname="one">1</label>
    <ul><li>
      <label data-tagname="two">2</label>
      <ul><li>
        <label data-tagname="three">3</label>
        <ul><li>
          <label data-tagname="four">4</label>
          <input type="text" id="startHere"/>
        </li></ul>
      </li></ul>
    </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This approach is verbose and inflexible. As the structure won't always be the same (some elements are nested 5 times, others 2), it doesn't solve the general case.

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for a solution along the lines of traversing up the DOM tree from point A, filtering the good stuff out, and stopping at point B. Maybe we go from A to B and push all of the elements we've selected to an empty array?

Comment: Could you please copy+paste the HTML in to the question. It saves people having to type out the HTML to test any solutions with, which can lead to inaccuracies.

Comment: All of the form is generated after an AJAX request (I call an XSD and use it as a framework to build form inputs etc. - idea is to make a UI that can be used to create XML files following XSD rules). https://jsfiddle.net/jd4gh89n/6/ can be used as an example though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.parentsUntil()` function to traverse up the DOM from each `INPUT` to the first `LI.parent`:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this
        .parentsUntil($this.closest('.stop-here').parent(), 'li')
        .map(
            function() { 
                return $(this).find('> label:first').attr('data-tagname');
            }
        )
        .toArray()
        .reverse()
        .join('_')
    ;
    
    $this.attr('name', name);
    $this.attr('placeholder', name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="stop-here">
    <label data-tagname="one">1</label>
    <ul><li>
      <label data-tagname="two">2</label>
      <ul><li>
        <label data-tagname="three">3</label>
        <ul><li>
          <label data-tagname="four">4</label>
          <input type="text" id="startHere"/>
        </li></ul>
      </li></ul>
    </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since you want to include `LI.stop-here`, we use its parent as the first argument to `.parentsUntil()`.

Then we use `.map()` to aggregate all the `data-tagname` attributes, typecast them to an array, reverse the order, and join them into a string using `_` as a delimiter.

Finally, we set the name of each `INPUT` to that name string. In your example, that's `"one_two_three_four"`.

Comment: Precisely how I thought this should work and what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your answer and your explanation.

Comment: Sure thing! I'm glad it helped.